# how to check picked date and todays date is equal

Tags: javascript, date

```
pickedDate = new Date(Date.parse(txtDate.value.replace(/-/g, ' ')));
todaysDate = new Date();
todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
if (todaysDate == pickedDate)
{
    return true;
}
    else
{
    return false;
}
```

I'm checking if picked date and today's date are equal and then returning `true` if they're equal or `false` if they're not, but condition is always false when i run the code.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that `todaysDate == pickedDate` tests whether the two variables reference the same object (instance) - which they never will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the following condition:

```
if (todaysDate.getTime() == pickedDate.getTime())
{
```

This should test for equality, because the getTime() method returns the Unix time of the object (as an integer) which can be compared against each other.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. You can use method .getTime() in regular JS.